# "Ajuste fino" no SELECT pra um sistema de ranking

Tags: mysql, select

Eu estou com dificuldades no uso do MySQL.

Andei perguntando aqui já, e fiz varios testes e progressos na elaboraçãoo de um select pra um *ranking*.

Tenho uma tabela "jogador" que guarda dentre outras infos, o `nome_jogador` e `pontuacao`. Essas duas infos me são necessárias pra criar uma consulta que me retorne um *ranking*, sendo o jogador corrente da app (sempre no centro exceto se for primeiro ou ultimo lugar), acima os jogadores (alguns) com a pontuação imediatamente superior à pontuacao do jogador escolhido, e abaixo os jogadores com a pontuacao imediatamente inferior à dele.

Na query eu consegui fazer isso, mas se tenho uma tabela com 30 jogadores, a minha consulta revela a pontuação do corrente, e a do jogador mais alto e mais baixo, ignorando os intermediarios mais próximos, que sao os que eu preciso.

Minha *query* atual:

```
select nome_jogador,pontuacao 
from jogador 
where pontuacao > (select pontuacao from jogador where id_jogador='4') limit 2 

union

select nome_jogador,pontuacao 
from jogador 
where pontuacao < (select pontuacao from jogador where id_jogador='4') limit 2

union

select nome_jogador,pontuacao 
from jogador 
where id_jogador='4' order by pontuacao desc;
```

Quero ajustar essa query pra mostrar os outros mais proximos do jogador corrente acima e abaixo. nao os das pontas da tabela.

peço encarecidamente socorro

Answer (score 3):

Faltou o `ORDER` nos primeiros `SELECT`s.

```
(
  SELECT nome_jogador, pontuacao
    FROM jogador 
    WHERE pontuacao > (SELECT pontuacao FROM jogador WHERE id_jogador=4 )
    ORDER BY pontuacao
    LIMIT 2
)
UNION
(
  SELECT nome_jogador, pontuacao
    FROM jogador 
    WHERE pontuacao < (SELECT pontuacao FROM jogador WHERE id_jogador=4 )
    ORDER BY pontuacao DESC
    LIMIT 2
)
UNION
(
  SELECT nome_jogador, pontuacao
    FROM jogador 
    WHERE id_jogador=4
)
ORDER BY pontuacao DESC
```

> **Só que tem um probleminha!**
>   a *query* posta na pergunta tem um bug, empates ficam sempre de fora.

### Solução para o bug do empate:

Acrescentando o campo `id_jogador` na consulta podemos garantir que o usuário seja sempre o do meio (caso haja quantidade suficiente antes ou depois dele) e ao mesmo tempo mostrar os empatados logo abaixo.

De brinde, ainda podemos fazer um `SELECT` a menos:

```
(
  SELECT id_jogador, nome_jogador, pontuacao
    FROM jogador 
    WHERE pontuacao >= (SELECT pontuacao FROM jogador WHERE id_jogador=4 )
    ORDER BY pontuacao
    LIMIT 3
)
UNION
(
  SELECT id_jogador, nome_jogador, pontuacao
    FROM jogador 
    WHERE pontuacao < (SELECT pontuacao FROM jogador WHERE id_jogador=4 )
    ORDER BY pontuacao DESC
    LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY pontuacao, id_jogador!=4
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95f34/1)**.

Se preferir não retornar o `id_jogador` também funciona, mas aí a ordem dos empates pode tirar o jogador desejado da linha do meio.

Caso prefira que os empates apareçam antes, só inverter a lógica e usar `<=` no `SELECT` de baixo, e `>` no de cima. Aí se ajustam os `LIMIT` e o `!=` do `ORDER`.